# Calling getDecorView for first time locks in the view. How to know if the view is locked?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-windowmanager

Here is the documentation for Window.getDecorView()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getDecorView()

As per this, when API is called for first time, various window characterstics are in lock mode. Which is fine. But is there a way to check if the current views in the window are in such lock state or not?
I'm trying to invoke a method like this:

```
private void replaceView() {
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    WindowManager wm = getActivity().getWindowManager();
    wm.removeViewImmediate(window.getDecorView());
    wm.addView(window.getDecorView(), window.getAttributes());
}
```

Now in certain use cases (like orientation change), when the above method is called for the first time, I get a crash.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{eebbc2d V.ED.... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
at com.airwatch.inbox2015.ui.email.MessageComposeFragment.replaceView(MessageComposeFragment.java:619)
```

Is it possible to know by some means that here I'm calling getDecorView() for the first time so removeViewImmediate() API may not work and thereby I can avoid calling that API?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[peekDecorView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#peekDecorView%28%29)** to discover the lock state.  It will "retrieve the current decor view, but only if it has already been created".  For example, in your Activity:

```
View decorView = getWindow().peekDecorView();
if( decorView == null )
{
    // Not created yet, maybe because setContentView was not called.
    // Calling getDecorView at this point forces creation, but also
    // "locks in various window characteristics", maybe prematurely.
    // You probably want to avoid that.
}
else
{
    // Window characteristics are locked in, and decorView is safely
    // ready to use.
}
```

Using `peekDecorView` avoids the side effects of `getDecorView`.  If this approach doesn't solve your crash problem, then hopefully it brings you closer to a solution.